# How to select the trace number, trace type and trace detection type for a Rigol Real Time Spectrum Analyser RSA5032N

Tags: python, pyvisa

I'm creating an interface to the Rigol real time spectrum analyser.

I'm using SCPI commands to communicate with the instrument with a "write and query" method using PYVISA. I have connected the spectrum analyser to my PC using LAN and succesfully configured it.

I have created an interface with start frequency, stop frequency and resolution bandwidth by using the following SCPI commands and it is working successfully by sending commands to the instrument.

```
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
inst = rm.open_resource('TCPIP::169.254.191.114::INSTR')
inst.write('SYSTem:COMMunicate:LAN[:SELF]:RESet')

def set_start_frequency(start_frequency):
    inst.write(f"SENSE:FREQUENCY:START {start_frequency}")

def set_stop_frequency(stop_frequency):
    inst.write(f"SENSE:FREQUENCY:STOP {stop_frequency}")

def set_resolution_bandwidth(resolution_bandwidth):
    inst.write(f"SENS:BAND {resolution_bandwidth}")
```

But, I want to select the trace number, trace type and trace detection. I have tried and many other SCPI commands.

```
inst.write('SENSe:DETector:TRACe2:AVERage')
```

Which SCPI commands do I have to use to select the trace 1 or 2, or 3, etc., and set the trace type "clear white or average or max hold or min hold ", then set the trace detection "positive or average or quasipeak"?

Comment: Is your question how to use PySimpleGUI to send any commands, or which commands you should send?

Comment: You can use 3 `Listbox` to select `trace 1 or 2, or 3`, `clear white or average or max hold or min hold` and `positive or average or quasipeak`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 which SCPI commands I have to use.